# Simple jQuery Slideshow Script by Jon Raasch error

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm using the Simple jQuery Slideshow Script by Jon Raasch (http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) and it works on my english version of the site, on the spanish version it doesn't work. It's the same code. I'm not sure why it works on one and not on the other one. All the files are linked correctly and I don't see an error in firebug.

English version (this one works)
http://www.stri.si.edu/

Spanish version (this one doesn't work, it stays on the first image)
http://www.stri.si.edu/espanol/index_test.php

Please help!

-Marisol

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you overwrote jquery on that page with prototype:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.stri.si.edu/js/prototype.js"></script>
```

why are you using such an old jquery version from 5 years ago?

anyway, the solution would be to either remove prototype if its not used for anything, or to use jquery.noConflict

The reason that your english page works is that you overwrite prototype with jquery on that page. this leads to to believe that you dont need prototype and can probably just remove it.

Comment: why do you need more answers if you have the solution right here

Answer (score 0):

You are running into conflicts with prototype.js. on both pages.  prototype and jQuery both use "$" as main object.

You will need to implement jQuery.noConflict();

Full instructions here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries